# Como chamar uma id hospedada no layout em activity estendida por Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment, webview

Bom, estou desenvolvendo uma app, em que se tem uma navigation drawer e nesta navigation eu coloquei para abrir cada item em uma nova activity, e em cada acitivty terá um layout, certo até agora tudo bem.
Mas agora, estou querendo chamar uma webview com progress bar, já está tudo feito no layout, mas quando vou chamalos por id (findViewById) na Activity apresenta erros, pois estou utilizando extends Fragment e não extends Acitivity. Neste caso, se eu substituir o Fragment para Activity, simplesmente  fica null, e a tela fica branca, sem nenhum conteúdo.
Vocês podem me ajudar a chamar esta Webview junto com Fragment?

Activity principal:

//Aqui é a parte da activity onde declara qual fragment será o principal, que será a primeira tela:

```
    if (id == R.id.home) {
        //Aplicar fragment principal
        home fragment = new home();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

E aqui está a activity home.java, como foi declarada anteriormente:

```
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


        public class home extends Fragment {

            public home() {
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // Chamando o layout nesta activity
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
            }
```

E aqui segue meu layout home.xml

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/progressBar"/>
```

O que eu quero, é declarar a webview e progressBar na activity home.java. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente, acho que você está confundindo um poucos os conceitos. Se a sua classe `home` estende um `Fragment` é porque se trata de um `Fragment` e não uma `Activity`.

É muito fácil manipular um `WebView` dentro do seu `Fragment`. Perceba que o método `onCreateView` retorna uma `View` inflada pelo `LayouInflater`. Essa `View` nada mais é que todo o layout do seu `Fragment`. Sendo assim tu pode alterar a classe `home` pra manipular o `WebView` da seguinte maneira:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        webView = (WebView) root.findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) root.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        return root;
    }
}
```

Com esses atributos definidos você pode manipular essas views à vontade. Poderia também passá-los pra `Activity` que contém o `HomeFragment`, como eu acho que era o teu intuito. Contudo, eu recomendo que toda operação relativa a esses elementos seja feito no `Fragment` ao qual eles pertencem.

Comment: Olá amigo, nem sei como te agradecer. Muito, muito obrigado. Você me salvou dessa. Valeu!

Comment: @TechPositivo de nada, fico feliz em ter ajudado.